# reading java class function variable in jsp page

Tags: java, jsp

I am trying to print value of a function variable in JSP Page. The function variable is located in java.class(com.project.bulk). File name is bulk.class. I tried reading the variable by writing below code in JSP file and it didn't work. Any help please?

```
<%@ page import="com.project.bulk.bulk" %>

<%=bulk.cellStoreVector %>
```

// function code is below

```
private static void printCellDataToConsole(Vector dataHolder) {

            for (int i = 0; i < dataHolder.size(); i++) {
                    Vector  cellStoreVector  = (Vector) dataHolder.elementAt(i);
                    System.out.println(cellStoreVector);
                    for (int j = 0; j < cellStoreVector.size(); j++) {
                          HSSFCell myCell = (HSSFCell) cellStoreVector.elementAt(j);
                          String stringCellValue = myCell.toString();
                         // System.out.print(stringCellValue + "\t\t");
                    }
                    System.out.println();
            }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't access a local variable outside that method or the block in which it is defined. The scope of local variable is confined in the block where it is defined.

Your below declaration is local to the `for-loop` in which it is declared. Even in the current method, it will not be accessible outside the `for-loop`. Because your loop defined a `scope` of access for this variable: -

```
Vector  cellStoreVector  = (Vector) dataHolder.elementAt(i);
```

To access it in a `JSP` outside your `class`, declare that field as a private instance variable in your class. And have a `public` accessor method, that will return the value of that field. Then in your JSP, you can invoke that method to get the value for a particular instance.

Remember, you need to access that method on an `instance` of your class. You are accessing here directly through your `class name`. If you want to access it like that, you need a `static` variable.

Here's a simple example covering what all I said above: -

```
public class Dog {

    // Private Instance variable
    private int instanceVar; // Defaulted to 0

    // Private Static variable
    // Common for all instances
    private static String name = "rohit";


    // Public accessor
    public int getInstanceVar() {
        return this.instanceVar;
    }

    public void setInstanceVar(int instanceVar) {
        this.instanceVar = instanceVar;
    }

    // Static public accessor for static variable
    public static String getName() {
        return name;
    }

}

class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Access static method through class name
        System.out.println(Dog.getName()); 

        Dog dog = new Dog();

        // Set instance variable through public accessor, on a particular instance
        dog.setInstanceVar(10);

        // Get instance variable value and asssign to local variable x
        // x is local variable in `main`
        int x = dog.getInstanceVar(); 

        showX(); 
    }

    public static void showX() {

        // x not visible here.
        System.out.println(x);  // Will not compile
    }
}
```

Comment: Rohit, I know you provided lot of important information. But for beginner like me, it will be helpful if you provide a small example. ?

Comment: @user1710288 It would be difficult to make you understand everything here. I would suggest to go through some basic tutorials of `Classes`. You can start with: - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classes.html

Comment: Rohit, I will do that and thank you for showing me right directions. Could you also post a simple example if possible?

Comment: @user1710288 Ok sure.. Edited my post. Take a look. :)

Comment: Thank you Rohit for taking your time and helping me. Your info is helpful to me.